# Can't understand why expression is evaluating to 0

Tags: algebra-precalculus

-1 - 3 - (-9) + (-5)
This expression is evaluating to 0, I don't know how when I do it on the paper I get to the answer -10 and are the parentheses changing the order of operation here if so what is to do first (-9) + (-5).

Comment: $-1-3=-4$, $-4-(-9)=5$, $5+(-5)=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The negative in front of $-9$ applies to $-9$ first.

\begin{align}
-1-3-(-9)+(-5) &= (-1)+(-3)+9+(-5)\\
&= 9-1-3-5\\
&=0
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Follow the BODMAS rule. When there is a series of Addition and Multiplication, you operate from left. $ -1 -3 -(-9)+(-5) = -4 - (-9)+(-5) = -4 +9 +(-5) = 5+(-5) = 0 $